# discord.py Send a message through a command that after a set time counts how many have “voted” for a reaction (custom emoji)

Tags: discord.py

I tried for days (and even unsuccessfully asked) that reactions counted on messages. The command I am working on is that of a vote that after a certain time automatically writes the results by counting precisely how much one reaction was voted in relation to another.
I would like to use custom emojis but I can't and even trying with normal ones I don't even count them and don't really know what to do.
I was able to do this with normal emojis but when I tried the same process with custom emojis the command locks on `thumbsup = len ([await i.users (). Flatten () for i in message.reactions if str (i. emoji) == please] [0])` 
How do I resolve?

Code:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["crp"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def conteggio_reazioni_personalizzate(ctx, *, proposta):
    favore = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Favorevole")
    contro = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Contrario")
    flore = get_emoji(ctx.guild, "Astenuto")
    message = await ctx.send(proposta)
    await message.add_reaction(favore)
    await message.add_reaction(contro)
    await message.add_reaction(flore)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    await message.remove_reaction(favore, client.user)
    await message.remove_reaction(contro, client.user)
    await message.remove_reaction(flore, client.user)
    thumbsup = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == favore][0])
    thumbsdown = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == contro][0])
    neutral = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == flore][0])
    await ctx.send(f"{thumbsup} a favore , {thumbsdown} contro e {neutral} astenuti")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/PC GIUSEPPE/PycharmProjects/LMIIBot Development/LMIIBot Development.py", line 442, in conteggio_reazioni_personalizzate
    thumbsup = len([await i.users().flatten() for i in message.reactions if str(i.emoji) == favore][0])
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\LMIIBot Development\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the message object so you can get all of the reactions from that message and filter the ones you want like this.

```
reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji = )
```

Then you can call the number of reactions you got and do whatever you want with that data.

```
print(reaction.count)
```

PS I know the reaction emojis can be hard to get, so I've collected the thumbs-up and thumbs-down for you!

Comment: I can see from the message that you use normal emojis.  I'm interested in the ones we can put on discord servers.  I know that the discord.py API speaks of "PartialEmoji" when it comes to using custom emojis.  my string works as long as it doesn't have to count and that string is made for simple emojis and NO custom.  I tried to put "PartialEmoji" but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Another thing: His method, however, also counts the reactions that have been removed.

Comment: After some thought, you can just replace the normal emojis with <:CUSTOM_EMOJI:>.